# Como contar o número de frequências de cada coluna em um data.frame no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Preciso contar o número de frequências em cada mês, onde cada mês é representado por uma coluna:

```
       USUARIO jan fev mar abr mai jun jul ago set out nov dez 
         1160   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  
         2505   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0           
         3042   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0              
         3554   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0
```

Como faço para obter o total de frequências de cada mês?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, vamos reproduzir os dados:

```
txt <- "USUARIO jan fev mar abr mai jun jul ago set out nov dez 
 1160   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  
 2505   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0           
 3042   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0              
 3554   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0 "

dados <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
dados
  USUARIO jan fev mar abr mai jun jul ago set out nov dez
1    1160   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2    2505   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0
3    3042   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0
4    3554   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0
```

Agora com os dados em mãos, o que faremos é transformar esses dados num formato *longo* ou *tidy*.

```
library(tidyverse)
long <- dados %>% 
  gather(mes, n, -USUARIO)
```

Com os dados no formato longo podemos criar um sumário com a soma dos 1s que aparecem para cada mês.

```
long %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(n))
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   mes       n
   <chr> <int>
 1 abr       3
 2 ago       2
 3 dez       1
 4 fev       4
 5 jan       3
 6 jul       4
 7 jun       2
 8 mai       3
 9 mar       3
10 nov       4
11 out       4
12 set       4
```

Comment: Sugestão:  Antes do primeiro pipe `lvls <- format(seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-01"), by = "month"), format = "%b")` e termine o `gather` com `%>% mutate(mes = factor(mes, levels = lvls))` para ter o resultado ordenado por mês do calendário e não por ordem alfabética dos meses.

Answer (score 5):

Uma forma de resolver este problema utilizando o `R` básico é através da função `apply`. utilizando o conjunto de dados fornecido pelo Tomás, temos o seguinte:

```
txt <- "USUARIO jan fev mar abr mai jun jul ago set out nov dez 
 1160   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  
 2505   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0           
 3042   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0              
 3554   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0 "

dados <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
```

A função `apply` tem três argumentos:

1. O conjunto de dados que vamos analisar em formato de array (pode ser data frame ou matriz, por exemplo)
2. Um valor igual a 1 ou 2. 1 indica que vamos aplicar uma função nas linhas da array, enquanto 2 indica que vamos aplicar uma função nas suas colunas
3. A função que vamos aplicar.

Para o teu problema, `apply` pode ser aplicado da seguinte maneira:

```
apply(dados, 2, sum)[-1]
# jan fev mar abr mai jun jul ago set out nov dez 
#  3   4   3   3   3   2   4   2   4   4   4   1
```

Eu utilizei o data frame `dados`, com a função `sum` aplicada em suas colunas (`2`). Como ele possui uma coluna usuário, é possível retirá-la ao final utilizando `[-1]`, que informa para o `R` retirar a primeira posição do vetor resultante da aplicação de `apply`.